# Frame shows nothing, neither does it show any error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

so after solving my first error due to the help of Hovercraft I finally started coding and getting stuff ready for my actual project. However, when I tried to add the label it now just shows me nothing at all, I mean if I remove the label and add any other stuff such as a button or so, it would show me the button but the  moment I add the jlabel to the code it just gives me a complete blank screen no matter what the property of the label be. The code of the project is as follow:

Main Frame:

```
public class Parking_Mania {

public static void main(String []args)throws Exception
{
    new GameFrame("Paking Mania");
}
}
```

Game Frame:

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame{

File info=new File("information.txt");

public GameFrame(String name) throws IOException
{
    if(!info.exists())
    {
        info.createNewFile();
    }
    this.setTitle(name);
    this.setSize(640,510);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);  

    Frames frame=new Frames();
    this.add(frame);
    frame.panel.show(frame, "opening");

}
}
```

Panel Class that handles changing different panels:

```
public class Frames extends JPanel{

CardLayout panel= new CardLayout();

public Frames()
{
    this.setLayout(panel);
    Opening op=new Opening(this);
    //nxtframe nf= new nxtframe(this);
    this.add(op, "opening");
    //this.add(nf, "nt");
    }

}
```

Finally the panel which should be showing itself on the frame:

```
public class Opening extends JPanel{


private Frames f;
private JLabel bg=new JLabel();
//private JLabel helpframe=new JLabel();
private JButton play=new JButton();
/*private JButton help=new JButton();
private JButton helpclose=new JButton();
private ImageIcon background;*/

public Opening(final Frames f){

    this.f=f;
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    //this.add(bg);
    this.add(play);
    //bg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/bg.jpg")));

}
}
```

Comment: Without creating JFrame how you can add components on it?Create JFrame (intialize) than add your all components after that set The frame visible.Second thing is you trying to add JFrame on Jpanel it should be vice versa

Comment: I doubt that I am trying to add jframe on JPanel can you please point out so I can correct it? Also I did create(initialize JFrame already, didn't I?) at the first class. Although I did remember that I should add components first before setting it visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components should be added to the frame before the frame is made visible.

Start with the working examples found in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The tutorial covers all the basics of Swing.

I would especially start with the tutorial on `How to Use CardLayout` for the first demo code to understand and modify.

The tutorial will show you how to better structure your code so that you don't keep extending panels, just to add components to a panel.

Comment: OMG that was the mistake!!! I never looked at the visible part before I wish I proofread my code before. PS: The reason I am extending panels is because the code looks more organised I mean so that my each class doesn't look soo clustered with code by this it makes it a bit less clustered and would look a little organised(Suggestion from my teacher who taught me java in last year(Grade 12)).